# Verificar imagem carregada

Tags: delphi

Existe a possibilidade de verificar quando uma imagem foi carregada dentro de um `TImage`?

Por exemplo: tenho um label que aparece "Carregando Imagem..." quando o `TImage` carregar qualquer imagem, esse label deve sumir. É possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim. Supondo que a imagem que você vai carregar é a partir da internet, você pode fazer assim:

```pascal
Var
 imageURL: string;
 MS: TMemoryStream;
 Jpg: TJPEGImage;
begin
 imageURL := 'URL da imagem aqui';
 try
   MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
   IdHTTP1.Get(imageURL, MS);
   if ms.Size > 0 then begin
     Jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
     MS.Position := 0;
     try
       Jpg.LoadFromStream(MS);
       Image1.Picture.Assign(Jpg);
     finally
       Jpg.Free;
     end;
   end;
 finally
   MS.Free;
 end;
```

No evento `OnProgress()` do componente `TImage` faça assim:

```
procedure TForm1.Image1Progress(Sender: TObject; Stage: TProgressStage;
  PercentDone: Byte; RedrawNow: Boolean; const R: TRect; const Msg: string);
begin
if PercentDone = 100 then
   Label1.Caption := 'imagem carregada!';
end;
```

Comment: Se vai carregar da internet no momento em que começar a renderizar a imagem, o label some. Pelo menos sumiu aqui. [Dá uma olhada](http://www.intowallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/hd-wallpaper-1920x1200-1024x6401.jpg)

Comment: Verdade @Filipe.Fonseca, antes de abrir a imagem ele some mesmo...da pra fazer algo nesse sentido ?

Comment: @user7605 a imagem é um JPEG?

Comment: Perfeito @Sunstreaker, obrigado!

Comment: @user7605 Só lembre de não utilizar imagens BMP, pois estas não fazem uso da rotina Image1Progress.

Comment: Ok, obrigado @Filipe.Fonseca